# How to store null value for date filed in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose-schema

I want to save Logintime,lunchoff time,lunchin time in a collection.When i am  login it should store logintime only and during lunch time i need to update lunchin time.

Comment: So what have you tried

Answer (score 2):

```
//when you login update user collection to update/change login time
let temp = {
    _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id),
    loginTime: new Date(),
};
Users.findByIdAndUpdate({
    _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)
}, temp, {
   new : true
},(err, user) => {});
```

Comment: i think i misunderstands, what you need is when you login at that time logingTime update in collection right ?

Comment: i just change my ans, try to use this.

Comment: when ever user loging you have to update loginTime so you can set current time